# Cassandra: UDF with map result gets CodecNotFoundException in Java

Tags: java, cassandra, udf

When executing a query with a custom aggregation function, I sometimes get a com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.**CodecNotFoundException** exception in the Java driver.

The result of the aggregation function is a map. I would expect that the Java API would have a codec for maps of standard types.

cqlsh also reports an error "Failed to format value OrderedMapSerializedKey", but shows the data in JSON format.

The final function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION average_by_source_final_1( state avg_type_1)
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    RETURNS map<text,double>
    LANGUAGE java
    ...
```

The aggregation is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE avg_by_source( text, double)
    SFUNC average_by_source_1
    STYPE avg_type_1
    FINALFUNC average_by_source_final_1
    INITCOND ((null, 0, 0.0), null)
;
```

I am assuming that a codec is needed for the return type of the final function, and not for the STYPE.

The exception from Java:

```
execution of 'average_by_source_1[avg_type_1, text, double]' failed: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException
... com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.FunctionExecutionException: execution of 'roger_ts_08.average_by_source_1[avg_type_1, text, double]' failed: com.datasta
x.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.FunctionExecutionException.copy(FunctionExecutionException.java:58)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
        at com.brocade.tspoc.CassandraDb.aggregateWithAggrFunc(CassandraDb.java:309)
        at com.brocade.tspoc.Main.aggregateWithAggrFuncTest(Main.java:223)
        at com.brocade.tspoc.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.FunctionExecutionException: execution of 'average_by_source_1[avg_type_1, text, double]' failed: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:130)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:174)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2600(RequestHandler.java:43)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:793)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:627)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
```

In cqlsh:

```
 avg_by_source(source, value)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 OrderedMapSerializedKey([(u'i1', 23.5), (u'i2', 1.2), (u's1', 50.0), (u's2', 15.0), (u's3', 8.0)])

(1 rows)
Failed to format value OrderedMapSerializedKey([(u'i1', 23.5), (u'i2', 1.2), (u's1', 50.0), (u's2', 15.0), (u's3', 8.0)]) : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sub_types'
```

Comment: The cqlsh part seems to be caused by bug [CASSANDRA-11534](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11534), which was recently fixed. The question is if this (cql bug) is related to the Java driver problem.

Comment: Version 2 of the Java driver documentation mentions [MapCodec<K,V>](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/TypeCodec.MapCodec.html). But the documentation for 3.1 only has the abstract version ([AbstractMapCodec<K,V>](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/TypeCodec.AbstractMapCodec.html)).

Comment: This may actually not have anything to do with the Codec. On a small data set my code works fine, but on a large date set it fails. But it fails inconsistently, sometimes in a few seconds and sometimes after a few tens-of-seconds. Sometimes it also fails with **AccessControlException** on FilePermission" "C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\logback.xml" "read".

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. With large data sets, I frequently still get the CodecNotFoundException, both in the Java client and in cqlsh.

Part of my question is based on an incorrect expectation. I had expected that the results would be returned as rows, with each map entry being a row. But the query result is a single row containing a map.

The code to read the results is:

```
Map<String,Double> map = queryResults.one().getMap( 0, String.class, Double.class);
```